# Learn multiple frameworks to work as a Web Developer, Freelancer

Tags: web-development

As a freelancer, do you have to learn multiple frameworks, programming techniques and other skills?

Although, I think this seems to add more distraction and decreases efficiency. However, when I started to working on some freelancing websites like [Freelancer.com](https://freelancer.com), I found that it was very difficult to find projects to work on when only focusing to work on one framework (in my case `Yii 2`).

Despite earning money, I really love programming. I don't know how this may seem

Answer (score 1):

To be honest alot of freelancer.com projects are based off of html. Go to freelancer and look at the categorys that they have. It will tell you the amount of jobs available for each subject and you can make your decision based of that. Obviously you would want to learn about the subjects that are in demand. Go take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the needs of your clients. Are they small mom-and-pop shop owners who need a brochure site? A simple php site will do.
Are they agencies who need a developer with a specific skill-set to augment their in-house team? Then learn that skill. It really is one of those "it depends" scenarios.